what dose this tsfresh version mean:'0.0.post0.dev58+ga42b9ea.dirty'?
i installed tsfresh with following commands:
conda create --name py310 python=3.10
conda install -c conda-forge tsfresh=0.20.2

then the magic happened:
conda list shows 0.20.2 but tsfresh.version shows 0.0.post0.dev58+ga42b9ea.dirty
(py310) ubuntu@10-23-173-171:~$ conda list tsfresh
# packages in environment at /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/py310:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
tsfresh                   0.20.2                     pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge

(py310) ubuntu@10-23-173-171:~$ python
Python 3.10.14 (main, May  6 2024, 19:42:50) [GCC 11.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tsfresh
>>> tsfresh.__version__
'0.0.post0.dev62+g3b829b5.dirty'

why the actual version is 'dirty', does it impact my usage? thanks!
i reinstalled the tsfresh with python 3.9 and got the same problem
